# Load and Parse XML in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, parsing

Below is my HTML

```
<table width="100%">
 <tr><td><center><b>Browse your XML File below.</b></td></center>   </tr>
 <tr><td><center><input type="file" id="location"></center></td></tr>
 <tr><td><center><input type="button" id="load" value="Load XML"></center></td></tr>
</table>
```

Below is my Code which I am using to load XML

```
$('#load').bind('click',function()
{
var localfile = $('#location').val();
alert(localfile);
var xmlDoc;
xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
xmlDoc.async = false;
xmlDoc.load(localfile);
if(xmlDoc.readyState == 4)
{
    alert("success"); // Till here this is executing fine...
    var readyXML = $.parseXML( xmlDoc );
    var xml = $(readyXML); 
    xml.find('Name').each(function()
        {
        alert($(this).text());
    });
}
});
```

It seems there is(are) mistake(s) in the code..

Please help me on this to correct the code..

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me that you parse an already parsed document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jQuery.parseXML` takes a string as first argument. Have a [look at the internals](http://jsfiddle.net/7KePK/).

```
xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
xmlDoc.async = false;
xmlDoc.load(localfile);
jQuery(xmlDoc).find('Name').each(function() {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: Bravo for looking at the implementation instead of just blindly relying on JQuery (one of my pet peeves) +1

Answer (score 1):

`xmlDoc.async = 'false';`

for a start